# How to concatenate quotes onto a string using spss macro syntax

Tags: spss

I have an excel worksheet containing thousands of file paths. I have imported them into an spss dataset. The goal is to rename the all the files that live within those paths. My plan is to run a mass `GET FILE` / `SAVE OUTFILE` loop to get it done. I already have code that 99% works.

The problem is that the file paths do not import from excel with quotations around them. So when I run my `GET`/`SAVE` macro there are no quotations around the file paths and the `GET FILE` can not run. I can not figure out the best way to add quotes around the file paths.

Here is the macro code I am using for the loop. Probably not the most efficient, but it does what I need.

```
SET MPRINT=no.

DEFINE !GETPATH (FPATH=!TOKENS(1) 
                 /VARG=!TOKENS(1)
                 /VARS=!TOKENS(1))

GET FILE=!FPATH.
COMPUTE nobreak=1.
AGGREGATE
/OUTFILE=*
/BREAK=!VARG !VARS
/nbval = N(nobreak).
COMPUTE nobreak=1.
MATCH FILES FILE=* /BY nobreak /LAST=last.


DO IF $CASENUM=1.
- WRITE OUTFILE='a file path here\getsave.sps' / 'GET ' 'FILE ' !VARG'.'.
- WRITE OUTFILE='a file path here\getsave.sps' / 'SAVE ' 'OUTFILE ' !VARS'.'.
ELSE IF NOT last.
- WRITE OUTFILE='a file path here\getsave.sps' / 'GET ' 'FILE ' !VARG'.'.
- WRITE OUTFILE='a file path here\getsave.sps' / 'SAVE ' 'OUTFILE ' !VARS'.'.
ELSE. 
- WRITE OUTFILE='a file path here\getsave.sps' / 'GET ' 'FILE ' !VARG'.'.
- WRITE OUTFILE='a file path here\getsave.sps' / 'SAVE ' 'OUTFILE ' !VARS'.'.
ELSE.
END IF.
EXECUTE.


GET FILE=!FPATH.
INCLUDE 'a file path here\getsave.sps'.
!ENDDEFINE.


!GETPATH 
FPATH ='filepath to dataset holding the filepaths\Data5.sav'
VARG  =GetFile
VARS  =SaveOutFile.
```

GetFile and SaveOutFile are the variable names holding the respective filepaths.

I have tried using the `!QUOTE()` and `!CONCAT()` commands in various ways such as:

```
/BREAK=!VARG !VARS 

'GET ' 'FILE ' !QUOTE(!VARG) '.'.

!LET !VAR1 = !QUOTE(!VARG)

!QUOTE(!CONCAT(!UNQUOTE(GET ), !UNQUOTE(FILE ), !VARG))'.'.
```

However, I can't seem to find away to get it to work.

What I expect to see is a file with many iterations of

```
GET FILE "abc.sav".

SAVE OUTFILE "xyz.sav".
```

that I can run.

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: try setting `mprint=on` and check the log to see where the syntax is breaking

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow - That's a really nice (first) question! Question: why are you using a macro? From your description it sounds like you have only one file that contains the list of paths - you can use the `write out` method just like you did without putting the process in a macro.

Comment: Another question - you seem to be writing out the same commands for all lines of the (aggregated) list - why are you separating the first-middle-last lines and repeating the commands?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your responses! When you mean repeating the commands I assume you mean the write outfile part? I will be honest, I am learning macro writing as I go with and have zero prior experience. Most of my code I have is me grabbing pieces from all over the internet. I kind of just took it for how it was, but if it can be simplified down I am all ears. I am really trying my best to learn and grow my skill set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the quotes as part of the non-dynamic text in the `write out` command:

```
WRITE OUTFILE='a file path here\getsave.sps' / 'GET FILE="' !VARG '".'  .
```

BTW this will work the same without wrapping it in a macro.
Unless you have a few files that contain lists, and unless there is a reason to differentiate between the first/middle/last lines in the list, the whole process could be done like this:

```
GET FILE="path\your file with the list.sav".
AGGREGATE / OUTFILE=* / BREAK=OrigName TargenName / n=n.
WRITE OUTFILE='a file path here\getsave.sps' / 'GET FILE="' OrigName '".' 
                                             / 'SAVE OUTFILE= "' TargenName '".' .
EXECUTE.
insert file='a file path here\getsave.sps'.
```

Comment: This is honestly so great! I was under the assumption that I had to write it in a loop to have it run through all the file paths, so this takes me by surprise. I ran it with some practice files and it works just as it should. Thank you so much on your help on resolving this!

Comment: Using `write out` to create a syntax and using spss macro (or python) are each very powerful automation tools in SPSS, most of the time you wouldn't need to combine them, unless you are facing some pretty complex tasks. Glad to be able to help...