# How to use data values in macro definition

Tags: spss

I have two datasets in a SPSS SYNTAX script. I need to change DATE command values depending on the values inside the first dataset as this DATE command affects the TSMODEL of the second dataset, how do I achieve this?

I figured out how to change the name of the datasets dynamically into a DO loop and build the right query in each case. But I wasn't able so far to dynamically change values for the DATE command.

```
define @getDataPronos (arg1 !TOKENS(1) /arg2 !TOKENS(1)) 
!DO !J = !arg1 !TO !arg2 !BY 5.
/*FIRST DATASET GETTING JUST ONE RECORD WITH YEAR (ANIO), MONTH (NPER)
GET DATA
/TYPE=ODBC 
/CONNECT='DSN=SQLFinal;UID=;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=IBM SPSS Products: Statistics Common;WSID=CJFSPSS;DATABASE=GeoEstadistica'
/SQL= !QUOTE(!CONCAT('SELECT TOP 1 ANIO, NPER FROM pronos.dat_corid_',!J,' ORDER BY anio, nper'))
/ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=255.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.

   !LET !startMonth = NPER.
   !LET !endMonth = 12.
   !LET !year = ANIO.

   DATASET NAME !CONCAT(PERIODO,!J) WINDOW=FRONT.
   DATASET ACTIVATE !CONCAT(PERIODO,!J).

/*SECOND DATASET PROCESSING TMODEL
   GET DATA 
     /TYPE=ODBC 
     /CONNECT='DSN=SQLFinal;UID=;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=IBM SPSS Products: Statistics Common;WSID=CJFSPSS;DATABASE=GeoEstadistica'
     /SQL= !QUOTE(!CONCAT('SELECT  CORID, TORID, PERLETRA, PROSID, CIRID, CIUID, MATID, MATERIA, ANIO, NPER, EXISTENCIAINICIAL, INGRESOS, EGRESOS, EXISTENCIAFINAL FROM Pronos.DAT_CorId_',!J, ' WHERE PROSID=0'))
     /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=255.
   CACHE.
   EXECUTE. 
   DATASET NAME !CONCAT(GRUPO,!J) WINDOW=FRONT.
   DATASET ACTIVATE !CONCAT(GRUPO,!J).
   SORT CASES  BY CORID. 
SPLIT FILE SEPARATE BY CORID.  
DATE M !startMonth !endMonth Y !year.

PREDICT THRU YEAR 2019 MONTH 12.
TSMODEL
   /MODELSUMMARY  PRINT=[MODELFIT]
   /MODELSTATISTICS  DISPLAY=YES MODELFIT=[ SRSQUARE RSQUARE RMSE MAPE MAE MAXAPE MAXAE NORMBIC]
   /MODELDETAILS  PRINT=[ FORECASTS]
   /OUTPUTFILTER DISPLAY=ALLMODELS
   /SAVE  PREDICTED(Pronosticado) LCL(LCI) UCL(LCS)
   /AUXILIARY  CILEVEL=95 MAXACFLAGS=24
   /MISSING USERMISSING=EXCLUDE
   /MODEL DEPENDENT=EXISTENCIAINICIAL INGRESOS EGRESOS EXISTENCIAFINAL
      PREFIX='Modelo'
   /EXPERTMODELER TYPE=[ARIMA EXSMOOTH] TRYSEASONAL=YES
   /AUTOOUTLIER  DETECT=OFF.
!DOEND
!enddefine.
@getDataPronos arg1=30 arg2=40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about SPSS macro is that it isn't capable of actual interaction with the data. It's sole function is to create and run the **syntax** that will interact with the data. 
A command like you wrote: `!LET !startMonth = NPER.` won't work because you're trying to skip a step - at this point the macro is just creating the syntax, the data isn't read yet and `NPER` has no meaning for the macro other than a four letter string.
In order to actually get your `DATE` function to be called dynamically based on values in the data, you should create new syntax that is dependent on the data.
One way to do this is using `write` command.
So for example, the active dataset has these variables `NPER` and `ANIO` which have values that you want to use in a command, you do this:

```
write out='path\my date command.sps' /"DATE M " NPER " 12 Y " ANIO ".".
exe.
```

Now the syntax is created (you can open it and check) you can run it like this:

```
insert file='path\my date command.sps'.
```

Note that the `write` command will create a new line with the command for each case in the data. If you only want to run the command once (assuming the values for `NPER` and `ANIO` are the same for all cases) you can do it this way:

```
do if $casenum=1.
   write out='path\my date command.sps' /"DATE M " NPER " 12 Y " ANIO ".".
end if.
exe.
```

Of course this can all be easily integrated into your macro, so you can bypass the problem you encountered and still use the rest of the macro as you did before.

Comment: BTW see another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57319091/how-to-concatenate-quotes-onto-a-string-using-spss-macro-syntax/57323313#57323313) for `write` command in a recent question.